# Add TextAppearance to TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have this TabLayout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout_chef_my_menu"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />
```

And I'm trying to add style to the titles, but When I add this line `app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabLayout"` this error shows up:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:344)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
```

Comment: Where did you put `android.support.design:tabTextAppearance`?

Comment: I added android:tabTextAppearance="@style/tabStyle" to my TabLayout and I got a compile error.

Comment: And what error is returned?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:344)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at 
`

Comment: It seems it can't found the tabTextAppearance attribute. but I don't know why.

Comment: Yes NullPointer says it can't be found here. Have you updated your sdk to the latest versions and work on a target-sdk that is high enough?

Comment: I'm using the 24 sdk version

Comment: did u initialized your `TabLayout` ?

Comment: please, show us @style/AppTabLayout as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until i was able to fix it using the guide in this website.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout#styling-the-tablayout

According to the article you need to first create your styles in this manner:

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Then go to your TabLayout and add **style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout_chef_my_menu"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
/>
```